# Teamcity Hybrid .Net Core + .Net Framework Solution

Tags: asp.net-core, teamcity, octopus-deploy

Our team is shifting slowly to `.NET` Core.

We have a CI/CD pipeline configured with `TeamCity + Octopus`.

There are plenty of tutorials explaining how to configure `TeamCity` to Build + Publish .net core solutions (e.g. https://rahulpnath.com/blog/build-and-deploy-a-net-core-console-application/) but I cannot find any explaining hybrid solutions (contain .NET core projects + .NET Framework projects)

Our current build pipeline in `teamcity` uses :

1. `NuGet` Installer to restore packages (it seems like .net core uses `.net` restore).
2. Visual studio 2017 to build the solution.

What needs to be done so that steps `1` and `2` also do what is needed for the new `.NET` core web `API` project? The project isn't currently showing in the build artifacts, so something is missing.

Do I need to set up separate `"dotnet restore"` and `"octo.exe publish"` commands for my .net core project? or can I somehow configure the existing NuGet + Visual studio steps to also include the .NET core project?